# place a button on top of overlay

Tags: css, input-field

I have a search screen
like this

[image]
. On click of search I am showing busy image with overlay.
But there is a stop button  is there in screen which I am not able to click because its coming under the overlay.
Can you pls help to solve this issue?

```
   <input type="button" value="Stop" style="z-index: 100;position: absolute;" />

 #overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  display: none; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 97.5%; 
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    
   z-index: 2;
   height:97.5%%;
   margin-top: .4%;
 }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on stackblitz?

Comment: @ holydragon how to reproduce.. The issue is straight forward and I have attached the screenshot also

Comment: i have done it by making the sidenav not showing overlay. thanks for ur comment

Answer (score 0):

if you test it alone it works. But i think the problem is that your stop button is a child of an element with a relative position. Maybe you must make the entire sidebar menu absolute or not covered by the overlay. Try also putting the stop button in the same level as the loader image, it more comprehensive that way.

```css
 #overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 97.5%; 
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    
   z-index: 2;
   height:97.5%%;
   margin-top: .4%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<input type="button" value="Stop" style="z-index: 100;position: absolute;" />
```